# What's the significance of this sentence in the tale "Ladri in chiesa" by Alberto Moravia?

Tags: meaning, short-stories, italian-language, alberto-moravia

The tale *Ladri in chiesa* (*Thefts in church*) belongs to the book *Racconti romani* (*Roman tales*) by Alberto Moravia. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any translation to English of this short story. My question is about the following sentence, which appears in this story:

> Così tutti hanno ragione e il torto non ce l'ha nessuno; e dalla ragione nasce la morte.

Translated to English, it would be

> So, everyone is right, and no one is wrong; and from rightness, death is born.

I have translated "right" and "rightness", but you have to know that "ragione" means "reason", so "dalla ragione nasce la morte" might be also been translated as "death is born from reason".

Taking into account that the story is set after World War II, I wonder about the significance of such sentence.

To provide some more context, I provide the beginning of the story, in which the above-mentioned sentence appears:

> Che fa il lupo quando la lupa e i lupetti hanno fame e stanno a pancia vuota, lamentandosi e bisticciandosi tra loro, che fa il lupo? Io dico che il lupo esce dalla tana e va in cerca di roba da mangiare e magari, dalla disperazione, scende al paese ed entra in una casa. E i contadini che l'ammazzano hanno ragione di ammazzarlo; ma anche lui ha ragione di entrare in casa loro e di morderli. Così tutti hanno ragione e il torto non ce l'ha nessuno; e dalla ragione nasce la morte.

I'll try to translate it to English:

> What does the wolf do when the she-wolf and the little wolves are hungry and their bellies are empty, whining and quarreling among themselves, what does the wolf do? I say the wolf leaves the den and goes in search of something to eat and maybe, out of desperation, goes down to the village and enters a house. And the farmers who kill him are right to kill him; but he also is right to enter their house and bite them. So, everyone is right, and no one is wrong; and from rightness, death is born.